# How does RANK() work in this query?

Tags: sql-server, duplication, rank

I want to delete duplicate rows from a table. I have searched for the query online, and found the following sample:

```
DELETE 
FROM dbo.LeadsContacts 
WHERE Sr_No IN
(
    SELECT Sr_No 
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
        [Rank] = RANK() OVER (PARTITION By Email, Campaign_Name ORDER By Sr_No DESC) 
        FROM dbo.LeadsContacts
    ) T
    WHERE T.Rank>1
);
```

I don't understand the flow and working of the query.  Can somebody please explain it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY xxx, yyy ORDER BY zzz)` provides a number ranking for each row where `xxx` and `yyy` are identical, and orders that list by `zzz`

The sub-query contained in your question:

```
SELECT Sr_No 
FROM (
    SELECT *,
    [Rank] = RANK() OVER (PARTITION By Email, Campaign_Name ORDER By Sr_No DESC) 
    FROM dbo.LeadsContacts
) T
WHERE T.Rank>1
```

returns a list of `Sr_No` values where the corresponding rows have duplicate `Email` and `Campaign_Name` column values, excluding the most-recent row.  The most recent row is excluded by the `WHERE T.Rank>1` statement, in combination with the `RANK() ... ORDER BY` clause return rows sorted in `Sr_No` reverse order (the `DESC`) keyword.

I used the following code to test your query against a small sample of rows:

```
USE tempdb;

CREATE TABLE dbo.LeadsContacts
(
    Sr_No INT NOT NULL
    , Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    , Campaign_Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.LeadsContacts (Sr_No, Email, Campaign_Name)
VALUES (1, 'test@test.com', 'campaign1')
    , (2, 'test@test.com', 'campaign1')
    , (3, 'test@test.com', 'campaign1')
    , (4, 'test@test.co.uk', 'campaign1')
    , (5, 'test@test.co.uk', 'campaign1')
    , (6, 'test@test.com', 'campaign1')
    , (7, 'test@test.co.uk', 'campaign2');


SELECT *
FROM dbo.LeadsContacts;

DELETE 
FROM dbo.LeadsContacts 
WHERE Sr_No IN
(
    SELECT Sr_No 
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
        [Rank] = RANK() OVER (PARTITION By Email, Campaign_Name ORDER By Sr_No DESC) 
        FROM dbo.LeadsContacts
    ) T
    WHERE T.Rank>1
);

SELECT *
FROM dbo.LeadsContacts;

--DROP TABLE dbo.LeadsContacts;
```

The only rows left in the table are:

```
    5, 'test@test.co.uk', 'campaign1'
    6, 'test@test.com', 'campaign1'
    7, 'test@test.co.uk', 'campaign2'
```